# Why is there some intermittent colour (green) when using gganimate()?

Tags: r, gganimate

I installed `gganimate` on Rstudio and followed the examples on their [vignette](https://gganimate.com/):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)

ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)) +
     geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
     scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors) +
     scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
     scale_x_log10() +
     facet_wrap(~continent) +
     # Here comes the gganimate specific bits
     labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'life expectancy') +
     transition_time(year) +
     ease_aes('linear')
```

However, when rendering the animation, it displays an intermittent green blip that makes it impossible to distinguish what is happening. I understand it is not a problem of `gganimate` but the rendering process. Certainly, I don't know what else to do.

In this link is the animation created

[image]

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0     
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin17.0                  
system         x86_64, darwin17.0          
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.4                         
year           2021                        
month          02                          
day            15                          
svn rev        80002                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
nickname       Lost Library Book
```

Comment: I don't get this green blip at my end. R version 4.0.3 and `packageVersion('gganimate')
 ‘1.0.7’`

Comment: Thanks, @RonakShah. However, I do. Don´t know if its R, Rstudio, the package or the computer.

Comment: I've been trying to replicate the same example on r and Rstudio on a windows 10 computer, and I have the same intermittence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: animate(anim, renderer = magick_renderer())

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot. Do you mind to elaborate? Why adding this correct the intermittence?

Comment: the gifski renderer gives problems in current version of Rstudio on Mac is my guess as read here:https://www.bountysource.com/issues/96854613-issue-with-gifski_renderer-flashing-green-background-magick_renderer-works Please tick answer if this solved your problem. Thanks